# Switching from Absolute Positioning to Floating on Right Margin on Browser

Tags: css

The CSS below positions a rectangle 639 pixels from the left side of the browser, no matter how big the browser is.

How could I make it so that the rectangle floats 30 pixels from the right edge of the browser instead?

```
.backgroundprofilead {
position: absolute;
width: 325px;
height: 595px;
left: 639px;
top: 200px;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
background: powderBlue;
}
```

Comment: replace `left: 639px;` to `right:30px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `right: 30px;` and remove the `left: 639px;`.